# Data not inserting into mysql table interestingly

Tags: php, mysql

I was making a review form in which a review will be taken from a textbox and inserted into the database. But the problem is that when I try running the code it gives the following error:

> Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\wamp64\path\to\file on line 12

The code that I wrote for doing the same is given below:

```
     <?php  
            require_once('data.php');
            require_once('connect.php');
            $personName = $_GET['name'];
            $value = $_POST['review'] ?? ''; 
            echo "<p>".$personName;
            echo "<p>".$value;



            $sql = "INSERT INTO reviews (name, review) VALUES ('$personName', '$value')";
            if($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Inserted";
            } else {
                echo "Not inserted";
            }

            ?>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <style>
            input[type=text], select {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 12px 20px;
                margin: 8px 0;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 4px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            button[type=submit] {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: white;
                padding: 14px 20px;
                margin: 8px 0;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 4px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            input[type=submit]:hover {
                background-color: #45a049;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
               <form class="" method="post" >
                   <label for="form-element"></label>
                <input type="text" name="review" class="form-control" id="review" placeholder="Enter anonymous review">

                       <button type="submit" class="menu">Submit</button>
             </form>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

It is interesting to note that everything that is stored in `$personName` and `$value` are being echoed correctly. But the problem appears when I try inserting the data stored in the variable into the database. This seems pretty disgusting topic. I tried to solve it the whole previous day but failed. Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Also, I haven't added prepared statements feature for the time being but I will add the same to prevent it from mysql injection attacks as soon as this problem is solved. 
[**P.S.:** I am still a beginner in PHP, So there are high chances that my mistakes are silly. Pardon if it is so. ]

connect.php:

```
 <?php
            $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
            if(!$connection) {
                die("Failed to connect" . mysqli_error($connection));
            }
            else {
                echo "";
            }

            $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'db2');
            if(!$select_db) {
                die("Database selection failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
            }
            else {
                echo "";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Before you continue to searh for the problem, please visit http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL injections and how to prevent them. Right now, a random user could delete your whole database within a few seconds without any need of deeper knowledge of your system. Please ALWAYS use prepared statements with you query the database with userinputs. **NEVER** put userinputs directly in your query. Always use prepared statements!

Comment: Also you wanna make sure that the form has been sent. Right now you execute the query even if the form hasn't been posted yet. (For example, when the page is loaded)

Comment: The error most likely suggests that the `$connection` does not contain a valid mysqli connection

Comment: I will add the functionality as I know how to add it. Right now, I am not even able to add anything to the database. Currently trying to tackle this problem. Prepared statements will be added. Thanks for the advice sir.

Comment: lucky PHP doesn't support multiple SQL statements so the DELETE injection won't work unless mysqli_multi_query() is been used. @Twinfriends but you are right the topicstarter should fix the SQL injection problem.

Comment: check your `connect.php` to see if mysqli object (`$connection`) was initialized successfully before the INSERT.

Comment: Add them now. Don't care about if the data is inserting right now or not. Simply do it. I was in the same situation as you for a long time and once it worked I was just to lazy to learn about prepared statements. Learn it from the beginning away. It takes 2-3 minutes to learn its so easy.

Comment: Yes, I checked the connect.php file and its connecting properly to the database @ildflue

Comment: The error says otherwise

Comment: @Sanu_012 If you are sure about that, you can execute some other simple query to check if you can get any thing through.

Comment: @Sanu_012 this is not right, obviously

Comment: I just added the connect.php coding into the question. Please have a look @ildflue and everyone.

Comment: I saw it, ` $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');``, maybe you could not initialize a mysqli object in this way

Comment: How do I do it then? @ildflue

Comment: I think you're leaving out code; you're probably closing the connection somewhere.

Comment: Please check the difference between `Object oriented style` and `Procedural style`. Use only one for all. You use `Procedural style` in conection.php, but `Object oriented style`  in your insert

Comment: I am also trying to figure out where I closed my connection from yesterday. It's becoming a cause for headache now. @FunkFortyNiner sir

Comment: Will there be anything wrong using OO style and Procedural style in different files @ildflue sir?

Comment: Not recommended, but the simplest way to test: change `if($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) ` to `if( mysqli_query($connection, $sql) === TRUE)` to see if can get rid of the error

Comment: @Sanu_012 if mysqli object is not initialized properly in connection.php, you do not have a valid object to use in other files.

Comment: @ildflue sir, I tried changing the code as you said but the same error is still flashing. This is getting bad for sure.

Comment: then i don't know the reason for now. sorry, could not help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165642/discussion-between-sanu-012-and-ild-flue).

Comment: That is what I am thinking ? I don't know why the error is saying otherwise. @MarvinFischer

Comment: Well I figured the problem out. I included an external file which had a code block along with which the $connection->close(); function was also there. That was the one which was closing my connection. Thanks to all. You all were right. It was a silly mistake as I presumed.  @ildflue and all. I am grateful to you. One last question: How can I redirect to the same page after inserting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "invoice";
$personName = "Bhaskar";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$value = $_POST['review']; 
echo "<p>".$personName;
echo "<p>".$value;


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql ="INSERT INTO tbl_review (name, review) VALUES ('$personName', '$value')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
input[type=text], select {
width: 100%;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
button[type=submit] {
width: 100%;
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 14px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
border: none;
border-radius: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
background-color: #45a049;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form class="" method="post" action="" >
<label for="form-element"></label>
<input type="text" name="review" class="form-control" id="review" placeholder="Enter anonymous review">

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="menu">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```